# How do I wait for an observable to update before executing more code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I think an observable may not be the right thing to use here but I'm not sure what else I could use to provide live updates of a variable's value to another class.

I have this loop in a service class

```
elements.forEach(element => {
  doStuff();
  this.numberSubject.next(valueFromDoStuff);
})
```

and a subscription to the observable in my component class

```
numberSubjectObservable.subscribe(result => {
  this.value = result
}
```

What I want is to be able to pause the loop until my Angular component is updated with the newest value from the subscription but right now it waits until the end before rendering the final value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386325/waiting-for-ui-re-rendering-to-complete

does this answer question?  It's similar to what you are asking

Comment: No, I don't see the relation to that problem..

Comment: You can use promises with doStuff, when result cames you call next.

Comment: @AloisoGomes I'm not sure I follow, I execute doStuff within a promise and put next() in the following .then()? That doesn't appear to make the component update at all

Comment: @Azuzu if you need doStuff result before call next promises will do the job

Comment: @AloisoGomes that doesn't solve the issue I'm having

Comment: @Azuzu I want help you. But i think we here need more details about what you want to achieve

Comment: @AloisoGomes Order of operations: perform operations on element in the loop, update the numberSubject with the next(value), receive that value in the component class and render the Angular component with the new value, go back to the loop and repeat the process

Comment: @Azuzu, one more question, re-render a component over each loop operation can result in memory leak. Wait last interation before rerender is not good?

Comment: @AloisoGomes the component is for a progress bar, I need to show progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your doStuff() is sync or async.
In case it is sync, you don't see any updates in your progress bar, because the change has happened instantaneously, so that you only see the final value.

In case it is async, first of all you have to forget about forEach, it [[does not work with it]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

I've prepared a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czqsqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice.ts) for you. The first button triggers synchronous iteration. The second button triggers an async iteration.

Faking an async doStuff:

```
private async asyncDoStuff(element: number): Promise<number>{
  console.log('running async doStuff with element: ' + element);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
   setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  }).then(()=>{return this.doStuff(element);});
}
```

And looping through your array to see the updates with a 1 sec delay:

```
public async asyncIterate(){
  let newElement = 0;
  for (const element of this.elements){
  newElement = await this.asyncDoStuff(element);
  console.log('newElement: ' + newElement);
  this.numberAsyncSubject.next(newElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case doStuff() is sync, is there a way to synchronously send progress values as it goes through the loop and ditch the observable altogether? In my case I cannot use a setter function for the component class because that will introduce a circular dependency

Comment: Is this of help? https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/easy-custom-progress-bar-in-angular-cb2670bb2d02

Comment: Otherwise you can use Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview or a npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-bar

Comment: I am using Angular Material's progress bar but the value to populate it comes from a separate service which is the reason I'm having trouble with it. However your code does seem to do what I need it to do, just need to tweak it a bit on my end to hopefully make it perform faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do here but if you need to wait on this.value to equal the numberSubjectObservable result you can use an async method and try the following

you can change this

```
numberSubjectObservable.subscribe(result => {
  this.value = result
}
```

to this

```
this.value = await numberSubjectObservable.toPromise();
```